# Display all menu levels

Tags: 7

I'm trying to output a menu with all of its submenus into a template file, currently I'm using the code below. The problem is that it only displays the top level links. If I pass the second $level parameter into menu_navigation_links it'll then only display that one level, not any of the others above or below.

How can I display all the different menu levels & still have the ability to add classes to the  as below? The title isn't really that important as I can 'hard code' that tag into the template file.

```
print theme('links__menu_top_page_navigation', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-top-page-navigation'), 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('main-menu', 'list-menu')), 'heading' => array('text' => t('Main menu'),'level' => 'h2','class' => array('main-menu-title'))));
```

The closest thing I've found so far is to use menu_tree_all_data() & menu_tree_all_output() but I cannot see how to edit the  class using that.

Comment: Is performance an issue? Are you OK with contrib modules for the job?

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid using contrib modules as there are quite a number installed on the site.

Comment: In that case I don't have a fast answer for you, sorry.

Comment: No worries, if you know of any other ways I'd welcome them when you have the time.

Comment: do you have a variable depth to the menu? or can you just reprint that line for each level (depending on the exact layout you are looking for)?

Comment: @Geoff The way the menu is currently structured is that it has a top level & some of those, not all, have sub menus. Then some of those submenus have submenus. I'd like it to be output as a nested unordered list but with the ability to alter the <ul> class. Would be nice to be able to alter the <li> class to but I think I can get around not having to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find an answer in a Stack Overflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30570027/1094862

For completeness I've copied the relevant code below:

```
$main_menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-name', null, 3);
render_menu_tree($main_menu_tree);

function render_menu_tree($menu_tree) {
  print '<ul>';
  foreach ($menu_tree as $link) {
    print '<li>';
    $link_path = '#';
    $link_title = $link['link']['link_title'];
    if($link['link']['link_path']) {
        $link_path = drupal_get_path_alias($link['link']['link_path']);
    }
    print '<a href="' . $link_path . '">' . $link_title . '</a>';
    if(count($link['below']) > 0) {
      render_menu_tree($link['below']);
    }
    print '</li>';
  }
  print '</ul>';
}
```